# Why does Foo(b) compile successfully in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, declaration

There is a strange behavior when I compile the below code:

```
class Foo {
};
int main() {
    Foo(b);
}
```

It compiles successfully even without declaration of `b`.
Any explanation for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a declaration itself. It declares a variable named `b` with type `Foo`, i.e. the same effect as `Foo b;`.

[[stmt.ambig]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig#1)

> There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving *[expression-statement](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.expr#nt:expression-statement)s* and *[declaration](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:declaration)s*: An *[expression-statement](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.expr#nt:expression-statement)* with a [function-style explicit type conversion](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv) as its leftmost subexpression can be indistinguishable from a *[declaration](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:declaration)* where the first *[declarator](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#nt:declarator)* starts with a `(`. In those cases the *[statement](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.pre#nt:statement)* is a *[declaration](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:declaration)*.

and [[stmt.ambig]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig#2)

> The remaining cases are *[declaration](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:declaration)s*. [ Example:
>
> ```
> class T {
>   // ...
> public:
>   T();
>   T(int);
>   T(int, int);
> };
> T(a);               //  declaration
> ```
>
> ...

Comment: Thanks songyuanyao. I thought it to create temporary.